# Weird bug - Subroutine runs only with a cout

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have the following...

```
int main(){

      cout<<"Before subroutine"<<endl;
      int returnvalue = subroutine();
      cout<<"After subroutine"<<endl;

}

int subroutine(){

      cout<<"Into subroutine"<<endl;
      /*subroutine does its work

        subroutine finishes its work*/
}
```

Now, the above works. That is, I am able to see "After subroutine" after the subroutine has finished.

However, if I comment out the line

```
cout<<"Into subroutine"<<endl;
```

in `subroutine()`, the subroutine simply does not seem to run. I never get to see "After subroutine" at all.

This seems like a bug. Is this a known problem for which there is any solution?

Comment: There must be some other bug in your code. Please show the complete code of `subroutine`.

Comment: sgar...Unfortunately, the other code within subroutine is specialized (I am actually solving a NonLinear Optimization Problem in subroutine). I am not sure that would help.

Comment: Please return, or declare subroutine void.

Comment: Once I make all the additions to get your code to compile on MSVC2010, I cannot reproduce the described behavior. Please give a complete, compilable example.

Comment: Sounds like either a race-condition, or overflowing some array or something, and with the print line, you just change the timing/space usage of the function.

Comment: Please don't post fake code. Post the code that you are running. Clearly you will need to cut it down. Make an SSCCE.

Comment: @Mats...Thanks. Is there a way to verify those? At my end, I will try running it on a different computer to see if that resolves is. But in any case, it seems strange.

Comment: @David. This is not a fake question. The subroutine in question is part of a larger math programming problem I am trying to solve. Let me possibly see whether I can isolate the problem further.

Comment: Well, this is what I tried and it works. I changed the Project Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Optimization->Maximize Speed (/O2) to Disabled (/Od). Now the code runs. Thanks all. Especially to Stefano Falasca who got me thinking about the "Optimization" setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subroutine might well be optimized out by the compiler, since it doesn't have any effect.

This, however, doesn't explain why

```
cout<<"After subroutine"<<endl;
```

isn't executed. Are you sure about that? Try placing breakpoints both into the subroutine and on the line "After subroutine".

Of course the return into the subroutine is absolutely needed.

Comment: Thanks Stefano. Your response got me to try out the "Optimization" setting in Project Settings. I changed it from maximize speed to disabled. Now, it seems to work. TY.

Answer (score 7):

You have undefined behaviour. The function **must** return an int:

```
int subroutine(){
  cout<<"Into subroutine"<<endl;
  return 42;
}
```

Also, make sure it is declared before `main()`:

```
int subroutine(); // declaration

int main()
{
  ...
}

int subroutine() { .... } // definition as before. But without bugs.
```

Comment: Actually, I do have return(0) at the end. I just have not mentioned it in the code above.

Comment: @Tryer ah well, I guess you should have mentioned it then.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs juan. Much appreciated. Stefano's answer got me thinking about the "Optimization" setting in the Project Settings. That seems to have resolved the issue.